# Скажите почему возникает ошибка ORA-00922: "Отсутствует или неверна опция"?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Почему возникает ошибка ORA-00922: "Отсутствует или неверна опция" и как её исправить?

Я просто только начинаю знакомится с pl/sql и вот возникает вот такая ошибка.
Мне нужно осуществить изменение данных в БД с помощью процедур(пакетов). Пользователь SCOTT/TIGER, таблица DEPT.
Вот текст заголовка моего пакета:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE dept_pkg IS
PROCEDURE Add_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2);
PROCEDURE Update_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2, A IN NUMBER);
PROCEDURE Delete_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER);
END dept_pkg;
/
```

Вот текст тела моего пакета:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE BODY DEPT_PKG IS
PROCEDURE Add_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SCOTT.DEPT(DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
VALUES(DEPTNOFIELD, DNAMEFIELD, LOCFIELD);
END Add_dept;
PROCEDURE Update_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2, A IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE SCOTT.DEPT
SET DEPTNO = DEPTNOFIELD
SET DNAME = DNAMEFIELD
SET LOC = LOCFIELD
WHERE DEPTNO = 'A';
END Update_Dept;
PROCEDURE Delete_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM SCOTT.DEPT
WHERE DEPTNO = 'DEPTNOFIELD';
END Delete_Dept;
END DEPT_PKG;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что у Вас не хватает ключевого слова `PACKAGE` в объявлении тела пакета.

Вместе `CREATE OR REPLACE BODY DEPT_PKG IS` должно быть написано `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DEPT_PKG IS`.

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое.
А не подскажешь еще вот что. Не срабатывает такой код, для ввода, редактирования, удаления...

Comment: `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`
`DECLARE`
`BEGIN`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(TO_CHAR(50, 'NIX', 'KHARKOV'));`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Update_Dept(TO_CHAR(60, 'EPAM', 'KHARKOV', 50));`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Delete_Dept(TO_CHAR(60));`
`END;`
`/`

Comment: Что именно не срабатывает, какую-то ошибку выдает?

Comment: выдает ошибку ORA -06550 pl/sql: statement ignore. Выдает каждый раз когда я пытаюсь обратиться к процедуре. То есть в моем случае 3 раза

Comment: и ошибку pls-00306

Comment: Если сделать запрос по другому, а именно без TO_CHAR

Comment: Вы каким-то странным образом пытаетесь передать параметры в процедуру. Для типа `number` нужно указывать просто число, без всяких кавычек. Для типа `varchar2` нужно указывать текст в кавычках. Вы, в первом случае, например, пытаетесь вызвать процедуру `Add_dept` передав туда один параметр - результат работы функции `to_char` в которую передаете сразу три параметра. Ни такой функции `to_char` которая принимает три параметра ни такой функции `Add_dept` которая принимает только один параметр строкового типа у Вас нет - от сюда и ошибки.

Comment: `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`
`DECLARE`
`BEGIN`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(50, 'NIX', 'KHARKOV');`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Update_Dept(60, 'EPAM', 'KHARKOV', 50);`
`SCOTT.dept_pkg.Delete_Dept(60);`
`END;`
`/`

Comment: Вызов должен выглядеть как-то так:  `DECLARE 
BEGIN 
  SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(50, 'NIX', 'KHARKOV'); 
  SCOTT.dept_pkg.Update_Dept(60, 'EPAM', 'KHARKOV', 50); 
  SCOTT.dept_pkg.Delete_Dept(60); 
END; 
/`

Comment: да, я об этом и начал писать.
если сделать, как указали вы, то выдает сразу 3 ошибки:
ora-04063 package body "SCOTT.DEPT_PKG" has errors 
ORA-06508 pl/sql could not find program unit being called.
ORA-06512 LINE 3

Comment: Видимо что то напортачил при создании процедур?

Comment: Эта ошибка говорит о том, что в теле Вашего пакета `SCOTT.DEPT_PKG` содержаться ошибки и Оракл не смог его скомпилировать. Сами вызовы процедур верные.

Comment: Да, откройте тело пакета на редактирование и попробуйте скомпилировать. Должны тогда увидеть ошибки.

Comment: ой, а как это сделать?

Comment: Ну скомпилировать не беда: `ALTER PACKAGE dept_pkg COMPILE /`

Comment: В общем создал в SQL Developer пакет dept_pkg, создал 3 нужные мне процедуры. Всплыли такие вот ошибки:
Error(4,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(6,3): PL/SQL: ORA-01747: неверные спецификации для user.table.column, table.column или column
Для вот такого кода:
`create or replace
PROCEDURE UPDATE_DEPT(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2, A IN NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE SCOTT.DEPT
  SET DEPTNO = DEPTNOFIELD,
  SET DNAME = DNAMEFIELD,
  SET LOC = LOCFIELD
  WHERE DEPTNO = A;
END UPDATE_DEPT;`

Comment: Ошибка возникает потому, что ключевое слово `SET` при `update` пишется только один раз. Т.е. Вам нужно написать: `UPDATE SCOTT.DEPT SET DEPTNO = DEPTNOFIELD, DNAME = DNAMEFIELD, 
  LOC = LOCFIELD WHERE DEPTNO = A;`
И вообще, если у Вас есть какие-то дополнительный вопросы - оформляйте их как полноценные отдельные вопросы. Тогда другие участники сообщества смогут их оценить и помочь Вам с ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Если процедура в пакете, то почему объявляется через

```
Create or replace?
```

Comment: Тогда просто указать вот так?

Comment: `BODY DEPT_PKG IS
PROCEDURE Add_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SCOTT.DEPT(DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC)
VALUES(DEPTNOFIELD, DNAMEFIELD, LOCFIELD);
END Add_dept;
PROCEDURE Update_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER, DNAMEFIELD IN VARCHAR2, LOCFIELD IN VARCHAR2, A IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE SCOTT.DEPT
SET DEPTNO = DEPTNOFIELD
SET DNAME = DNAMEFIELD
SET LOC = LOCFIELD
WHERE DEPTNO = 'A';
END Update_Dept;
PROCEDURE Delete_Dept(DEPTNOFIELD IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM SCOTT.DEPT
WHERE DEPTNO = 'DEPTNOFIELD';
END Delete_Dept;
END DEPT_PKG;
/`

Comment: по моему с начала нужно создать заголовок пакета, а потом создать тело пакета, вот от сюда и получается  `CREATE OR REPLACE BODY DEPT_PKG`